# Aggregation or Dependency in the Simple Factory (UML)

Tags: python, design-patterns, uml, factory, aggregation

In a course I'm taking, a `PizzaStore` uses a `simplePizzaFactory` class that handles concrete pizza instantiation, described with the following diagram (as provided in the course material):
[image]

Code that I re-wrote in python:

```py
# Pizza's superclass and it's subclasses are defined elswhere

class SimplePizzaFactory:
    def create_pizza(self,type_of_pizza):
        if type_of_pizza == "cheese":
            pizza = CheesePizza()
        elif type_of_pizza == "pepperoni":
            pizza = PepperoniPizza()

        elif type_of_pizza == "clam":
            pizza = ClamPizza()

        elif type_of_pizza == "viggie":
            pizza = ViggiePizza()
        else:
            raise Exception("You need to specify a type of pizza.")
        
        return pizza


class PizzaStore:
    def __init__(self, pizza_factory_obj):
        self.pizza_factory_obj = pizza_factory_obj

    def order_pizza(self,type_of_pizza):
        type_of_pizza = type_of_pizza.lower() 
        pizza = self.pizza_factory_obj.create_pizza(type_of_pizza) 
        pizza.prepare()
        pizza.bake()
        pizza.box()
        return pizza

print("========================================================")
factory = SimplePizzaFactory()
store = PizzaStore(factory)
store.order_pizza("Cheese")
store.order_pizza("viggie")
```

**Question:**

Generalized by (from the course material):

[image]

I'd understand that the first arrow is aggregation (since an object of the simplePizzaFactory is created and sent to the PizzaStore as an argument) but how is the second arrow is also aggregation? shouldn't it make more sense to be a dotted dependency arrow?

I'd appreciate more clarification on this part and on my understanding as well if I was incorrect regarding the first arrow.
Any comments on the code would be also appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd understand that the first arrow is aggregation (since an object of the simplePizzaFactory is created and sent to the PizzaStore as an argument)

This is not because the constructor (or any other method) of the *PizzaStore* (*Client*) receive an instance of the *SimplePizzaFactory* that there is the first aggregation nor even a simple association.

For me both aggregations are wrong.

- the *SimpleFactory* does not know the *Client* using it, so a fortiori there is no aggregation
- the *Product* does not know the *SimpleFactory* creating it, so a fortiori there is no aggregation.

The diagram can be (*Pizza* is *abstract* but may be it is an *interface* ?):

[image]

Note in your first diagram the relation between *SimplePizzaFactory* and *Pizza* is wrong too in the sense there is no attribute in *SimplePizzaFactory* to memorize instances of *Pizza*, contrarily to *PizzaStore* having an attribute to save an instance of SimplePizzaFactory*, it is much clear to use a dependency stereotyped *create*.

Comment: Indeed and even if it did make sense, the aggregations in the course material are likely the wrong way around. Client would aggregate Factory, not the other way around!

Comment: @muszeo absolutely

Comment: Nice one! I just discovered it after having answered a similar but more detailed question from the same OP.  Would I have known, would I have referred to this excellent answer!